# I need to add a table to a Oracle SQL database

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, addition

I need to add a table to Oracle SQL Database that takes current system time and I keep getting issues with:

> "00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"".

I need two columns one that takes the current sysdate and the other to take a date

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
ADD (<Colum1> TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), <Column2> TO_DATE('yyyy/mm/dd'));
```

Comment: Do you need a new table or to add new columns to an existing table?

Comment: If you need to add a table, why are you using the syntax to add a column?

Comment: Add columns to an existing, sorry

Comment: -1 for laziness because your statement contains several syntax errors. Searching the web for "Oracle table add column" returns tons of examples for the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your current table's name is mytable, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (current_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, mydate DATE);
```